# SQL: Substring until second character starting from right keeping left values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this filename `AAAA_BBBBB_CC_HDDD_HGGG.csv` and I'm trying to keep the values after the second underscore starting from the right.

So i want to keep any values just before `_HDDD_HGGG.csv`

This is my code:

```sql
SET @NFileN =  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@source_filename),1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@source_filename), CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE (@source_filename), 0) + 1)))
```

And this is the returned value:

```
(6 rows affected)
_HDDD_HGGG.csv
```

Instead of being `AAAA_BBBBB_CC`.

Does anyone has a clue for this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking a SUBSTRING from 1 till your CHARINDEX while your string is reversed. Either reverse your string again or use LEN to find the length of your string like so:

```
REVERSE(
  SUBSTRING(
    REVERSE(@source_filename),
    CHARINDEX('_',
              REVERSE(@source_filename), 
              CHARINDEX('_', 
                        REVERSE (@source_filename), 
                        0)+1)+1,
    LEN(@source_filename)
  )
)
```

p.s.: Added a second +1 to remove the "_" between CC and HDDD

p.p.s: CHARINDEX is a SQL Server function which I assume is what you are actually using. The MySQL equivalent would be POSITION, the equivalent for LEN would be LENGTH